Adjust Ephemeral Port Range in Yocto
I'm currently trying to build a Linux image with Yocto Kirkstone. The final image will include an application that requires the ephemeral port range for ip4 to be edited a certain way.
Is there a way to provide a .bbappend recipe to have the ephemeral port range configured by default? How can this change be made or do I need to change this by hand in the final image by changing the values in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range?

This is all just entries in /etc/sysctl.d/. So, just drop a file like 50-set-ephemeral-ports.conf in there, containing net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1234 5678 (or whatever your port range limits are). So yes, this is a really simple layer to add!
